# _asdict in Python 3 namedtuple subclass returns empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

How can I use `_asdict` from a Python 3 subclass of `namedtuple`?

This is what I've tried:

```
class A(namedtuple('B', 'c')):
    pass

a = A(3)

a._asdict()
{}
```

This works fine in Python 2 and returns:

```
OrderedDict([('c', 3)])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I found out, this behavior was listed as a bug in [*Issue 24931*](https://bugs.python.org/issue24931) and fixed. The correct behavior is present in version `3.5.2` (Python `2.x` was not affected by this.)

Using my current version of Python (`3.5.2`) this performs as expected:

```
class A(namedtuple('B', 'c')): 
    pass

A(3)._asdict()
Out[7]: OrderedDict([('c', 3)])
```

So, in short, either consider updating to `3.5.1+` or, if you cannot, implement `_asdict` yourself; this is [stated in a message](https://bugs.python.org/issue24931#msg256995) on the issue tracker and seems like a viable alternative:

```
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

class A(namedtuple('B', 'c')):
    def _asdict(self):
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))
```

behaves as you need.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading python is not so easy though. But your link has a good workaround in: https://bugs.python.org/issue24931#msg256995

Comment: I see @Oin , I'll include that short work-around for anyone else who might bump into this! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `namedtuple` from `collections`. Tested with Python 3.5.2:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>>
>>> class A(namedtuple('B', 'c')):
...     pass
...
>>> a = A(3)
>>>
>>> a._asdict()
OrderedDict([('c', 3)])
```

What do you expect from the empty dictionary at the end?

```
>>> {}
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with Python 3.x that has been resolved somewhere between 3.4.2 and 3.4.5.

To get `_asdict()` working on affected versions set `__slots__ = ()` on your class:

```
class A(namedtuple('B', 'c')):
    __slots__ = ()
```